# OutputDataReceived stops when an input is required

Tags: c#

I'm using OutputDataReceived to print the output of a process in a RichTextBox. Sometimes, the proccess requires some user input, and I can't handle my conditions because the user needs to enter the input in the same line, not a new line, so the condition never fires up and the program stops waiting for an input.

```
public ASFProcess(ASFui asf, RichTextBox rtb)
{
    _asf = asf;
    ASF = new Process();
    output = rtb;

    var ASFInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        Arguments = "--server",
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        Domain = "",
        FileName = Properties.Settings.Default.ASFBinary,
        LoadUserProfile = false,
        Password = null,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
        StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    };

    ASF.StartInfo = ASFInfo;
    ASF.OutputDataReceived += OutputHandler;
}

private void OutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.EndsWith("input:"))
    {
        var result = Interaction.InputBox(e.Data, @"Enter necessary input");
        ASF.StandardInput.WriteLine(result);
        ASF.StandardInput.Flush();
    }

    ...

}
```

For example:

```
This line is printed in the richtextbox, because it doesn't require an input.
Enter your input: _ (This is when the prompt must be shown)
This line is never shown because the process is waiting an input.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier for you to do the same thing but in Console, that being said.

Textboxes are not made to trigger events on every input, because that would trigger an event on every character you add.

If you really want to use a Textbox, i would suggest adding a "Submit" button beneath the Textbox, which you can use to trigger an event.

OR

you can bind a button like Enter to throw an event when your cursor is inside the textbox and you press Enter

Comment: The second option sounds more like what you want ?